# change source extension to destination

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I'd like to change the extensions of specific files in my folder from source extension to destination.
I tried to use the ${var%pattern} method but I can't get it right.

```
#!/bin/bash
folder="$1"
source="$2"
dest="$3"
files="$(ls "$folder")"
for file in $files; do
    if [ "${$folder/file: -${#source}}" == "$source" ] 
    then
            mv "$folder"/"$file" "$folder"/"${file%.$source}.$dest"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

First: do not parse `ls`. Use an array to store the list of files, and the expression in your comparison is syntactically incorrect. The use of `%` is, ironically, correct.

```
files=( "$folder"/* )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $f = *.$source ]]; then
        mv "$f" "${f%.$source}.$dest"
    fi
done
```